# Where does the creation of permissions live in Django?

Tags: django, debugging, django-permissions

I need to do some debugging, because the permissions for one of my models are created wrongly. So I tried to find the piece of code where Django creates the permissions upon syncdb and writes them in the database, but I haven't been successful at all; maybe I just overlooked the right lines of code, but if somebody can point me out the right module / line of code where this happens I'd be very happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`create_permissions`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py); note that it is wired up to fire when it receives the `post_syncdb` signal.

Comment: Thanks! Already thought it would run on post_syncdb, that's reason I wasn't quite sure where to look for it in the first place, as it could be really anywhere!

Comment: Yeah, I wound up having to use Google Code Search on it. I was expecting it to be in __init__.py or something.